# Why does EF add tons of unused OUTER APPLY clauses when I put OrderBy at the beginning of my query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**tl;dr;** Putting `orderby contact.Property` before my projection (`let defaultAddress = contact.Addresses...`) creates an exponentially more complex SQL statement and sometimes causes an OutOfMemoryException.

Question

I have a simple data model for storing contact information

```
public class Contact {
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    //etc
}

public class Address {
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

I want to project that into a flat model and sort the results, for example

```
from c in Contacts
let a = c.Addresses.FirstOrDefault()
orderby c.DOB
select new {
    ContactID = c.ContactID,
    AddressID = a.AddressID
}
```

That generates straightforward SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
        [Extent1].[DOB] AS [DOB], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent2].[AddressID] AS [AddressID]
            FROM [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ContactID] = [Extent2].[ContactID]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[DOB] ASC
```

If I switch the order of the `orderby c.DOB` to be before `let a = ...`, EF adds an entire extra `OUTER APPLY` statement to the generated SQL.

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ContactID] AS [ContactID], 
        [Extent1].[DOB] AS [DOB], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent3].[AddressID] AS [AddressID]
            FROM [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ContactID] = [Extent3].[ContactID]) AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent2].[AddressID] AS [AddressID]
            FROM [dbo].[Addresses] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ContactID] = [Extent2].[ContactID] ) AS [Limit1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[DOB] ASC
```

The query gets significantly more complicated and has *exponentially* more unused OUTER APPLYs, LEFT JOINs and CROSS JOINs if I add more collection properties to my projection or if I add a filter to the collections.  If the query is has enough flat properties putting the orderby in the wrong place will cause an OutOfMemoryException while trying to build a query plan for the massive SQL that gets generated!

Comment: Instead of a projection, you could use a `SelectMany` to flatten your structure, which might reduce the complexity of the underlying query.

Comment: Why? Nobody is perfect. LINQ query translation to SQL is a complicated task, hence there is always chance to miss the case and make non optimal implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's not just non optimal.  For a non-trivial query, it's enough of a difference to cause the app to crash with `OutOfMemoryException`!

Comment: @just.another.programmer I know (I've seen your previous post). My point was that there is no special reason (why do we have bugs in the programs we write) - it is how it is because of improper implementation based on missed case, wrong assumption and many similar reasons..

Comment: @IvanStoev I see what you mean.  Is there somewhere I can/should report it to the EF team?  Now that I've figured out exactly where the problem is, I can just rewrite my queries, so it doesn't affect me so much anymore.

Comment: You can try reporting it here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues, but IMO all the current efforts are on EF Core, so I doubt it will be fixed. But who knows :)

Answer (score 0):

It requires intimate knowledge of EF's source code to understand how the SQL generator parses an expression into SQL. It's not my ambition to dig that deep (that would take many days), so unless someone from the EF team chimes in, I guess we have to live with the facts as they are.

It's always good to know about issues like this. Having seen more issues at Stack Overflow, it seems a rule of the thumb emerges:

#### Sort as late as possible in a LINQ statement

Another case I already knew of is a query like `Set<T>().OrderBy(...).GroupBy(...)`. Here, the `OrderBy` doesn't cause a bad query shape. It's ignored completely! Conversely, the statement `Set<T>().GroupBy(...).OrderBy(...)` does translate into a SQL `ORDER BY`, but of course the statements are semantically different.

Comment: I just got word from the EF team on my github issue.  They consider the case where an orderby is ignored if a later group/join happens to be *by design* b/c it matches the behavior of LINQ in general!  (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/354#issuecomment-328687033).  Seems like your "rule of thumb" may be more of a "requirement"!

Comment: Well, with all due respect, this isn't true. The behavior of `OrderBy - GroupBy` in LINQ to objects is as expected: the object in the groups are ordered according to the preceding `OrderBy`. Maybe it's not *guaranteed* to be preserved, but that's something else.

Comment: I completely agree with you, I'm just passing on the "official" position of the EF team on this.